# New motherboard, hard drive and SSD, Windows 8.1 won't install and is boot looping

Tags: windows, computer-building, windows-installation

First let me start by thanking those who take their time to help me on this one, it's not going to be easy to solve this. I've been trying to fix this for 4 months on a daily basis, and I'm at my wits end, beyond frustrated. I will try to explain the dynamics of the situation the best I can, but it's convoluted. Let me give the background, I have gone through 3 new motherboards, 3 new hard drives and a new optical drive. I also purchased a second Windows 8.1 in case it was a disk issue.

First, the Windows 8.1 disk installed with no problem on other computers that are up and running. Here is the issue. 
First motherboard and a new hard drive were purchased. I build the computer. It runs for 2 months, during a Windows update I get the infamous automatic repair restart boot loop on my M2 SSD, which I still cannot fix. I bought a new motherboard (I broke the CPU pins in an effort to fix this issue).

I received a new motherboard along with a purchase of a WD Black 500GB hard drive. I set up the new build, triple checked all things correct (my 75th build) started the system with CSM turned on along with legacy settings, installed Windows 8 disk.. black screen for 60 seconds, then restart, no spinning install circle.. This boot loop won't stop. I tried every form of setting possible for 3 days straight. Frustrated I threw a Windows XP disk in and instantly it installed. While it confirms my CPU, MB, HD all work, since upgrading from XP to Windows 8 isn't possible, I have to wipe the drives. So I reformatted the hard drive. I didn't know how to handle the SSD, having read that they can't be formatted.

So I sent everything back to Newegg. I got a new motherboard, but I still had the same problem. I know my knowledge of MBR and GPT and formatting is weak, so I spent 50 hours studying everything I could find. The truth is, I just don't fully understand this aspect of computers. I think, but I'm not sure that the hard drive issue not accepting the Windows 8 install may be MBR related. I used a Hirens Boot CD to restore the MBR. I assumed that it worked, but I still can't get Windows to install.

My Issues:

- I have an SSD that is stuck on automatic repair boot loop. It shows that screen for 3 seconds and restarts.
- I have a hard drive that won't accept Windows installation either. It sits on a blue square screen for 60 seconds and restarts.

I have tried the following:

1. Created a Windows Media Creation installation USB from the Windows website. (I'm supposed to set up a hard drive to allow installation, but it doesn't work.)
2. I have tried the developers ADK called  Windows Pre-installation Environment (Windows PE) http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39982

It didn't work. I don't know what to do. I use my computer to make a living, and to be honest, I'm about to lose everything, all because I can't get Windows to install!

I have built high-end overclocked rigs for a decade, over 75 systems, and I've never had a problem until Windows 8.1. I am struggling to learn UEFI. I'm getting old, and it's hard for this old dog to learn complicated new tricks. I'm at my wits end. I spent over 100 endless hours reading everything I can trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. While I learned a great deal, I can't overcome this problem.

Finally I  have a new SSD on its way that should be here by Wednesday, in hopes that I could connect it and be able to install, ending my problems, but reading the links on the side of your website, I get the impression that I need to know a bunch of codes and stuff to get that to work too. My head hurts from it all. I can no longer afford to pay a company to set this up for me. I've lost a thousand in the last few months from this, and me being stubborn wanting to fix it myself. I do have a Geek Squad account paid for, do you all think Geek Squad can handle fixing this type of issue? I have my doubts about them, but I do have a paid for account. I am reaching out to you all in hopes I can with the help of others, overcome this issue myself and you all.

I apologize for the digressions and convoluted explanation, In the end, all I can say is I've tried everything. Is anyone willing to take my challenge on and help me walk through this? I would be very grateful, and promise that in the future, I will help someone else, in their time of need when I can, in return for any help I receive from individuals here. Thank you for your time.

Comment: SSD disks can be formatted exactly the same way as rust disks are formatted, I've done it myself. Quick formatting an SSD takes about a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Run some diagnostics, such as :
Try running a live distro, check for any issues. Have you tried any other operating systems? If the issue persists then you know it is something wrong with your hardware. The boot record may be corrupting itself for whatever reason. Whilst yes, it is inadvisable to wipe an SSD in the same traditional methods, due to their limited read/write cycle, it is perfectly fine to do so every once in a while. 
Conclusion: Try running a different operating system for a few weeks to see if any problems arise. Although in my opinion it sounds like an issue with your storage devices.

Comment: I tried windows XP and it installed immediately, but cant upgrade from XP to win 8, so I had to wipe that drive, I suspect that when I used the format drive option from windows xp, that I screwed up the drive.I will check out live distro, Just for the record, Ive tried this with only 1 drive, and only keyboard and mouse, I have windows 8 installed  on a different computer, but when I swap drive to the new comp wont work. . Can anyone tell me how to move a HDD to a new computer?

Comment: Moving over a hard drive physically is easy to do and only requires a screwdriver and the power cable and data cable. However you cannot just start the computer up resume using the operating system as normal, unless the hardware was IDENTICAL. By the sounds of it either your boot record is corrupting itself or your hard drive is experiencing faults. Depending on the age it may still come under warranty? Either that or try installing Windows 8 on a different drive. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick read of your issues and I noticed you might have issues similar to those that I had recently. My desktop has 3 hard drives, 2 SSDs and a mechanical hard drive. SSD1 had a Linux installation, and what I tried to do is install Windows 10 Preview on the mechanical drive and Windows 7 on SSD2.

I installed everything in MBR (I used GParted to switch to MBR) using legacy boot. What I noticed is that in order for the Windows installation to work properly on my setup **I HAD** to set the hard drive where it's being installed as the **MAIN BOOT DRIVE**. For example, when I tried to install Windows 10 on the mechanical drive, while having SSD1 as the main boot drive, the installation didn't want to boot up, it just froze.

Another thing that happened during downloading Windows updates is that all my installations got messed up and I ended up with a boot loop. My guess is that installations/updates need to have the actual boot drive of the system set as the main boot drive. Once I do that, everything works properly.

Comment: Thanks for response, how does a person set a hard drive as MAIN BOOT DRIVE, It was my understanding HDD no longer use the master/slave system since launch of Sata..

Comment: They don't, what I'm talking about is the boot order setting in BIOS. Sorry I wasn't clear. Check what the current setting for the first boot device is. If the optical drive is the first boot device, or the mechanical drive, change it back to the SSD where you want to install Windows. Then use the quick boot device selector (F12) in my case to boot off of the installation media (don't select the UEFI boot option if you're using legacy boot mode).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I am grateful. I don't want this to be taking the wrong way, I don't mean any offense in any way, but I have tried all the basic, standard, even upper level "fixes" nothing works. Why don't any of the MB manufacturers write direction that diagram, or outline step by step, how to configure the settings?  I tried swapping the hard drive from the computer Im using, to the new computer, that doesn't work. Can someone point me to a webpage that will provide me instructions on how to swap drives from one computer to another?

Comment: Well then in that case I can't really help you, sorry. I have no idea what could be causing problems, at least not like this, "over the wire"... Best of luck finding a solution...

Comment: @Richard *Why don't any of the MB manufacturers write direction that diagram, or outline step by step, how to configure the settings?* I guess it's because the settings are specific to the hardware and there's too many models of hardware to put in a tutorial, so many MB manufacturers put the advice about the settings in their product forums instead, which can be a gold mine of useful information.